# LINQ - select()

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два класса:

```
 public class Order
 {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string OtherData {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}

    public long UserId {get;set;}
 }
 
 public class Item
 {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public Order Order {get;set;}
    public OrderId {get;set;}
    public string OtherData {get;set;}
 }
```

И по определённым причинам мне необходимо из БД брать данные в таком виде:

```
        List<string> orderIds = {}; // список ордеров, которые нужно вытащить из БД
        var items = _dbContext.Items
            .Include(item => item.Order)
            .Where(item => item.Order.UserId == userId) // userId определён по коду заранее
            .Where(item => orderIds.Contains(item.OrderId))
            .ToList();
```

И всё бы ничего, код работает, но далее мне нужно взять список ордеров:

```
        var orders = items.Select(x => x.Order).ToList();
```

И если среди `items` окажутся такие `item`, которые принадлежат одному ордеру, то вполне логично среди `orders` окажутся дубликаты. Собственно, вопрос: как можно группировку сделать? Или как можно брать только уникальные `order`?

Пока единственное, до чего я дошёл:

```
List<Order> uniqueOrders = new List<Order>();
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if (!uniqueOrders.Any(x => x.Id == order.Id))
         uniqueOrders.Add(order);
}
```

Но меня не покидает ощущение, что в LINQ нужный мне функционал уже заложен, а я не совладал с гуглом и не смог такой функционал найти.

Comment: Сгруппировать - `.GroupBy()`. А уникальные, скорей всего вам нужен `.Distinct()`.

Comment: `_dbContext.Orders.where(o=>o.UserId == userId).where(o=>orderIds.contains(o.id)).ToLIst()`?

Comment: @tym32167 , оно, конечно, да. Но по некоторым причинам приходится сначала брать именно ``items``, причём именно с ``Include(x=>x.Order)``. А раз так, то мне бы не хотелось ещё раз к БД обращаться за той информацией, что уже взята

Comment: Что это за причины то такие?

Comment: @tym32167 , ответ сравнительно длинным получится. Тут можно как-то обсуждение в чате открыть?

Comment: можно, но мне в чатах неогда сидеть. Можете это в вопрос свой добавить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
var noUniqOrders = items.Select(x => x.Order).ToList();
var orders = noUniqOrders.Distinct(x => x.Id);
```

Т.е. если Id из базы, то distinct выберет только уникальные orders.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы слегка развернул запрос и сначала выбрал ордера с ихними деталями

```
List<string> orderIds = {}; // список ордеров, которые нужно вытащить из БД
var orders = _dbContext.Orders
    .Include(o => o.Items)
    .Where(o => o.UserId == userId) // userId определён по коду заранее
    .Where(o => orderIds.Contains(o.Id))
    .ToList();

var items = orders.SelectMany(o => o.Items).ToList();
```